# How to set esFactory host address dynamically in elastic search using angular?

Tags: angularjs, elasticsearch

I have created a json which have the key value pair of my host address. I need to set the client host as the value which is mentioned in JSON?

```
app.service('client', function (esFactory) {     
    return client = esFactory({ 
        host: 'http://192.168.1.76:9200'
    }); 
});
```

Want to make the 'host:' value to be read from a property/JSON file.

Answer (score 1):

Finally I found an alternate solution for this. Since my intention is to update the configuration details from a property file or JSON file, I done the same in another manner.Apart from calling the JSON/property file using http calls I statically maintained the JSON throughout in my application by importing using script tag in my html. The problem which I faced during using http calls is time delay. The host will default assign to localhost address before completing the ajax call for JSON reading and to take the content from JSON. So when we mention the JSON file in script tags in html page it will load on when DOM creates and then we can access the data in JSON every were in our js.

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this

```
app.factory('elasticClient', ['esFactory', function (esFactory) {
    return esFactory({
        host: 'http://localhost:9200',
        sniffOnStart: true,
        sniffInterval: 300000
    });
}]);
```

Please check [AngularJS-ElasticSearch](https://github.com/vhvinod/AngularJS-ElasticSearch)

Comment: @vinod_sh this is not the thing am looking for.. i want to set the value in the host which i need to catch from json